# SQL : transform union query to a single query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database schema like this

**User**
id
matricule

**Document**
id
title
user_id(foreign key to user)
mode( can accept PUBLIC or PRIVATE)

I want to retrieve all document which are public and all documents which belongs to a given user(matricule)

I did a union query like this :

```
select * document d
Inner join user u ON u.id = d.user_id 
and u.matricule ='matricule1'
UNION
select * from document d
Inner join user u ON u.id = d.user_id 
where d.mode ='PUBLIC'
```

which works well but can i achieve the same result with another way( i read somewhere that union queries are bad for performance) like subquery for example ?

Thank you very much

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . I am using postgreSQL .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select distinct *
from document d
Inner join user u ON u.id = d.user_id 
where u.matricule = 'matricule1' or d.mode ='PUBLIC'
```

`SELECT DISTINCT` to remove duplicates just as `UNION` does. (Perhaps you want just `SELECT`?)

Comment: So fast . Thank you very much :)

Comment: If he has primary keys in both tables (*as most tables should*) then is the `DISTINCT` really necessary, since he's getting back `*`? This is just nitpicking and speculation and I thought to just throw this idea out there, I +1'ed anyway.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, probably not needed, but OP hasn't specified pk's.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want the columns from the `document` table, this can also be written as:

```
select * 
from document d
where exists (select * 
              from "user" u
              where u.id = d.user_id
                and u.matricule = 'matricule1')
or d.mode ='PUBLIC'
```

This makes removing duplicates unnecessary which `UNION` does implicitly and would be necessary for a `JOIN` solution.

But you **have** to check the execution plan for both solutions. In some cases the `UNION` solution might indeed be faster then the above (or a `JOIN`). This depends heavily on the DBMS being used (e.g. for Postgres or Oracle I wouldn't expect a big difference at all in this case)

Comment: .Thank you very much , another great solution too . +1 :) . How can i check the execution plan for a query ? Do you have a good link please ?